# Combining two tables in the most efficient way

Tags: sql, postgresql

wouldI have two tables that have the following columns:

```
table_1: id, date, val1, val2    
table_2: id, date, val3, val4
```

I now want

```
table_3: id, date, val1, val2, val3, val4
```

Both tables have a unique index on (id, date).

At the moment i just create a new table.

```
create table table_3 as
select * from table_1 join table_2 using (id, date);
create unique index my_index
on table3(id,date);
```

As the data is very large this takes a while. I was now looking for ideas to make this faster.

The question is: Do you think altering table 1 by adding the missing columns and then inserting them would be faster, as the index should not have to be recreated? Any other way to speed this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way is almost certainly what you are doing. Trying to alter the table will end up updating each row in the table and index. It's quicker to rebuild the index at the end.

The other alternative of course is to make table_3 a view.

Comment: The point if is I only update values in columns where no index is present, will the index have to update anyway?

Comment: That's not what you're doing though. You're adding columns and so rewriting the entire table anyway. Search for "HOT" updates regarding PostgreSQL optimisation to allow updates without index updates - only applicable if the row stays on the same data page.

Comment: So maybe when I create table 1 with cols 1 and 2 I can create 3 and 4 as well and populate them with nulls until I have the data from table 2.

Comment: Only going to help if most of table 1 has no corresponding rows in table 2. If you need to update most of table 1 you're probably better off doing drop-index, rebuild, rebuild-index.

Comment: Ok, they have the exact same values. I just find it strange that if if i update a value not indexed that the index needs to be recalculated.

Comment: The index points to a block on disk. Updating a row creates a new version on disk and marks the old one as deleted (search for "mvcc"). Since you are updating every row in the table you would need more than 50% free space in each block to update all the rows without moving the updated row onto a different block. You can set a "fill factor" for tables to allow this. Unless this is a regular operation though, it's not worth wasting the space. All that unused space still needs to be read/written from/to disk + RAM.